# Is there any way to safely stop/resume database replication programmatically?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am wondering if there is a way to stop/resume safely database replication programmatically from C# code. Do you have any suggestions? By "safely" I mean that the subscriber database must remain in the consistent state.

Comment: By very definition, stopping replication will allow the subscriber to fall out of consistency with the publisher.    Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Curt Well, I need to perform some long-running queries on a replica, the point is I want replication process to be stopped during that. The nature of queries doesn't allow to perform some of them on one database state and the rest on another (some tables could be changed by running replication).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via Replication Management Objects (RMO).

RMO allows programmatic control of Replication via the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.aspx) namespace.

Have a look at [Replication Management Object Concepts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146869.aspx) to get started.

Keep in mind that RMO is deprecated and may be removed in a future release of SQL Server. I've created a [Microsoft Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/774485/rmo-api-deprecated-in-sql-server-2012) to request that Microsoft reconsider the deprecation of the RMO API. If you feel that it is important, please up-vote it.

The recommended replacement to programmatically control replication is T-SQL.